# Shell Script to Recursively Loop Through Directory and print location of important files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I am trying to write a command line shell script or a shell script that will be able to recursively loop through a directory, all its files, and sub-directories for certain files and then print the location of these files to a text file.

I know that this is possible using BASH commands such as `find`, `locate`, `exec`, and `>`. 
This is what I have so far. `find <top-directory>  -name '*.class' -exec locate {} > location.txt  \;`

This does not work though. Can any BASH, Shell scripting experts help me out please?

Thank-you for reading this.

Comment: Do you want to get absolute path to each found file?

Comment: Yes, that would be awesome - because then I would know exactly where it is. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the redirection by using `find`'s `-fprint` option:

```
find <top-directory>  -name '*.class' -fprint location.txt
```

From the [man](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) page:

> -fprint file
>   [...] print the full file name into file file.  If file does not exist when find is run, it is created; if it does exist, it is truncated.

Comment: That's a GNU extension -- not available in `find` implementations that only comply with the POSIX standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html

Comment: I voted for Akos for the answer because this user has much fewer points and had some clearer syntax with the <top-directory> part of the script. Also, I was unaware of the -fprint option before this. Thanks er'body especially @pdw . :D

Comment: I like how `fprint` saves time with not having to create a file. with `cat` or `touch`.

Comment: @user3808269, you don't need to use `cat` or `touch` regardless (particularly not `cat`, which doesn't actually create files at all); `>location.txt` creates the file as-is.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `find` (if you don't specify any other action) is to print the filename. So you can simply do:

```
find <top-directory> -name '*.class' > location.txt
```

Or if you want to be explicit about it:

```
find <top-directory> -name '*.class' -print > location.txt
```

Comment: will it loop through all the files and sub-directories for any .class files though or just stop at the first one it finds? Thank-you for the quick answer btw. :D

Comment: It gives relative path - not absolute which is what the OP is looking for

Comment: @user3808269 It will list all matching files in all subdirectories.

And if you run the find command with a absolute path, it will print absolute paths. If you start it with a relative path, it will print relative paths.

Comment: ...well, if you want an absolute path, just make it `find "$PWD/dir"`.

Comment: Oh wow. This works. Thanks pdw and @CharlesDuffy for the help

Comment: The command is correct. I'm guessing you tried the wrong directory, or perhaps you don't have any class files.

Comment: dir can be a confusing statement in a script since this is a dos command in Bill Gate's Windows. Just offering some helpful friendly feedback. :D Thank-you again for the helpful help.

Comment: @pdw i did try the wrong directory at first... I forgot where the .class files were. I should of moved up one directory probably and then looped around all the sub-directories. :D

Comment: @CharlesDuffy also, take a look at `-print0`. It will preserve spaces in the filenames. Not an issue with this call it doesn't look like, but when you use fine and are feeding input to something else, it becomes an issue

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, are you sure you meant to direct that to me? I'm very, *very* familiar with `find -print0`, and a frequent proponent of the `IFS= read -r -d ''` idiom. Then again, if one were using GNU extensions here, `-printf '%P\0'` would bear mention as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy (smacks self). Sorry Charles, I knew you knew, but I apparently read the comment below your and attributed it you by mistake. (must be getting old)

Answer (score 0):

## A less preferred way to do it is to use `ls`:

```
ls -d $PWD**/* | grep class
```

let's break it down:

```
ls -d # lists the directory (returns `.`)
ls -d $PWD # lists the directory - but this time $PWD will provide full path
ls -d $PWD/** # list the directory with full-path and every file under this directory (not recursively) - an effect which is due to `/**` part
ls -d $PWD/**/* # same like previous one, only that now do it recursively to the folders below (achieved by adding the `/*` at the end)
```

## A better way of doing it:

After reading [*this*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) due to recommendation from [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy), it appears as a bad idea to use both `ls` as well as `find` (article also says: "`find` is just as bad as ls in this context".) The reason it's a bad idea is because you can't control the output of `ls`: for example, you can't configure `ls` to terminate filenames with NUL. The reason it's problematic is that unix allows all kind of weird characters in a file-name (newline, pipe etc) and will "break" `ls` in a way you can't anticipate.

Better use a shell script for the task, and it's pretty simple task too:

Create a file `my_script.sh`, edit the file to contain:

```
for i in **/*; do
    echo $PWD/$i
done
```

Give it execute permissions (by running: `chmod +x my_script.sh`).

Run it from the same directory with:

```
./my_script.sh
```

and you're good to go!

Comment: what does the -1 one do in this script? Where is the directory to be searched through specified? Thanks for the reply. Interesting.

Comment: @user3808269 good catch, I was playing with it and forgot to remove the `-1`. I'll add explanation in the answer for the rest.

Comment: -1; read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for a detailed description of why `ls` should never be used programatically.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the link - I'll read it right after I tuck the kids in to bed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the link! I updated my answer, do you mind having a look and give your review, I'm not a such a great shell-script writer and would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @alfasin it seems to me you want that glob(star) expression to be `"$top_directory"/**/*.class` – that way it doesn't just try to find all the files on the entire filesystem. Then, the `$PWD/$i` part is unnecessary because the expansion of `$i` will already contain the entire path.

Comment: Well -- if you're iterating over `/**/*`, you don't want to prepend `$PWD`. That would make sense for `**/*`, or would be completely unnecessary for `$PWD/**/*`. Beyond that -- quotes; `echo $i` does string-splitting and glob expansion, whereas `echo "$i"` means you leave runs of whitespace and such alone, and using `printf` instead of `echo` provides more control over formatting; for instance, `printf '%s\0' "$PWD"/**/*` would give you a stream of NUL-delimited names, ready to pipe into `xargs -0` or a `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename` loop.

Comment: (As a matter of convention, by the way -- if a script is written to be sourced, it's appropriate to give it a filename extension indicating the appropriate interpreter [so `.sh` only if it's POSIX-compliant; `.bash` if it uses bash extensions; etc]; if it's intended to be used as a command, by contrast, commands don't conventionally have extensions on UNIX, just as you don't run `ls.elf` -- see https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful for more on the subject).

Comment: ...to be clear about how `find` _can_ be used safely: `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do something_with "$filename"; done < <(find . -print0)` is, while relying on GNUisms in `find` and bashisms in syntax  (`<()` is used here to allow `something_with` to modify the shell's state -- let's say you were modifying variables or such based on what `find` found -- whereas a pipeline would result in a subshell that disappeared after the loop ended, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for more on this) safe for all valid filenames.